# Formatting Sharepoint List Date or Choice Column with JSON

Tags: json

I am very new to all this. I dont really know what most of these codes are, but with a little searching and trial an error I achieve my goals by changing bits and pieces. My current goal is to format a fields background color depending on the value of that field.

I found a very nice post on the subject. The problem is I need to combine a couple examples and I am having a problem. Here is the post.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting.

I have a date field called "Proposal Due Date". When the date is past, I want the BG one color. When the date is approaching (5 working days out) I want the BG another.

Below are the 2 examples I found and edited. I can only do one or the other. I need them both in the same format column box.

I can do the first part easy. It makes the BG a redish color if the date is past... Except it included todays date.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "debugMode": true,
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if([$Proposal_x0020_Due_x0020_Date] < @now, '#FAAAAA', '')"
  }
}
```

The second part is a bit tricky for me. I dont know how to make this check 5 working days ahead instead of just 5 days. I also dont know how to prevent it from including days past.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "background-color": {
      "operator": "?",
      "operands": [
        {
          "operator": "<=",
          "operands": [
            "[$Proposal_x0020_Due_x0020_Date]",
            {
              "operator": "+",
              "operands": [
                "@now",
                432000000
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "#FCFC00",
        ""
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I found part of my solution.

I got them combined. Now I just need to make the 2nd part look 5 working days forward instead of just 5 calendar days.

Comment: I have...
if([field] <= @now+432000000, '#FCFC00', ' ')

What can I change to make if ignore weekends and holidays?